# display different value for the same variable at each loop

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a variable "derniere" (derniere: 200,1000,400)
In the part send infos, I want to display the value at each iteration into the parameter 'response time'.
How can I push value of derniere at each loop into the part 'send infos' because this part is into a another function. Don't pay attention to the part Configuration.
Thanks for you help

```
// ******** HIDE VAR ARR ***********
for(const key in arr){
    var region = arr[key].region;
    var Value_t = arr[key].Value;
    var key_t = arr[key].cle    

    //********** HIDE CODE CONFIGURATION ************

    cw.getMetricStatistics(params2, function(err, data) {
      if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {       
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
          tableau = data.Datapoints[i].Average;         
        }
        derniere[key] = (parseInt(tableau));    // Send into the part send infos
      }
    });

    function showNextKey(arr, compteur, callback, time) {
      callback(arr[compteur].cle);
      compteur++;

      if(compteur < arr.length) {
        setTimeout(showNextKey, time, arr, compteur, callback, time);   }
      };
    }

    // ********** SEND INFOS ****************
    function sender(cle) {       
      const gekoq = require('gekoq');
      const push = gekoq('******'); //Geckoboard API Key
      push({
        key: cle, //Widget Key
        data: {
          "status": "up",
          "downTime": "-",
          "responseTime": derniere // /!\ Display value at each loop
        }
      }).then(response => console.log(response));
      console.log();
    }

    setTimeout(showNextKey, 2000, arr, 0, sender, 2000);
```

Comment: Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I feel like your code could be cut down to a dozen lines max for us to be able to see and reproduce the problem. Right now, you're forcing us to read through a lot of code that is unrelated to your specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed some parts of the code, I post the rest to better understand my approach